# webcrypto solution on IE 10 and android 4.x

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

Is it a way to find a polyfill to support webcrypto on IE10 and Android4.x?
I found webcrypto-shim for IE11.

I need webcrypto in Jose-jwt plugin in Javascript to do client side encryption of some datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Cryptography API is not supported in IE11 or Android (if you mean the WebView), but it is available in Android browser and Chrome for Android

See http://caniuse.com/cryptography/embed
[image: webcryptoapi support]

`Webcrypto-shim` is targeted to fix legacy browsers using partial or non-standard implementations such as IE11 and Safari8, but you will not find a full polifyll for older browsers because a native implementation part is needed, at least the key storage

To encrypt data in client sid you could use another javascript library, since you do not need any specific function of WebCryptographyApi, but of course, this depends on your jose-jwt library

Comment: So it is impossible to have a pure Js for full polyfill that can be used in IE10 or Android4.x devices?

Comment: **IE10**: A full polyfill would require native support. **Android4.x**: Depends on browser and version. But JWT encryption does not need a full polyfill, so I think you could adapt jose-jwt or use other cryptographic library

Comment: I was trying to find where is the native implementations missing to be able to create webcrypto polyfill on IE10 or android 4.x but couldn't find it anywhere.  and key storage is supported from IE8. Anyone spent some time on that before?!